# Why the ES6 code and ES5 code has diffent result after compiling by Babel.js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

**The ES6 code:**

```
let foo = 'outer';

function bar(func = x => foo){
    let foo = 'inner';
    console.log(func());
}
bar(); // outer
```

The Result is "outer".

**The ES5 code compiled by Babel.js:**

```
'use strict';

var foo = 'outer';

function bar() {
    var func = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? function (x) {
        return foo;
    } : arguments[0];

    var foo = 'inner';
    console.log(func());
}
bar(); // inner
```

The Result is "outer".

I don't know why they have different result.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [bug in Babel](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7204). Expressions in complex parameter lists should not be able to see declarations in the body of the function, but the code generated by Babel here evaluates the default parameter in the scope of the function, where the inner `foo` is visible.

Comment: Any chance there is an issue created already or are you keen to create one? In either case it would be helpful if you updated your answer with a link to one.

Comment: Added the link. (Initially skipped it because babel's bugtracker is pretty terrible.) Interestingly, the code in the bug is exactly that in this question, so I'm worried I missed the point of this question.